# Updating Label with HashMap value

Tags: java, javafx

I have an issue, with binding a Label *someLabel* with a value.

So there is a class with a HashMap field used as an inventory:

```
public HashMap<Animals, Integer> inventory = new HashMap<>();
```

I need to display this Integer value live, like a timer of some sort.

The thing is, I tried to use *bind* property on the label, but it wil show only the initial value, and there are some issues with binding, as it wants a *SimpleStringProperty* class instance as a property. While my `get(Object key)` method is called, it returns a *String* after my modification, and won't let me do it...

Please point me in the right direction, should I monitor every time the method `put()` is called, to keep the label on the live by `setText()`?

Comment: You can't bind to an `Integer`; it has no mechanism for notifying the bound value of changes. You need to use [JavaFX properties](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) (and perhaps JavaFX collections) if you want to respond to changes in the values.

Comment: Use, for example, a `SimpleIntegerProperty` which implements [`ObservableIntegerValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableIntegerValue.html)

Comment: Thanks guys, these are really good waypoints.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` does not implement `Observable`.

However JavaFX has `ObservableMap` which does implement `Observable`:

```
ObservableMap<Animals, Integer> inventory = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

Label label = ...
Animals key = ...

label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.valueAt(inventory, key).asString());
```

or for more control

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> Objects.toString(inventory.get(key), "n/a"), inventory);
```

Comment: This one looks good, I most definitely will look this one up.